# How do I convert a string like "Red" to a System.Windows.Media.Color?

Tags: wpf

I know I can go the long route by...

1. Adding a reference to System.Drawing
2. Creating a System.Drawing.Color from the string
3. Creating the System.Windows.Media.Color from the ARGB values of the System.Drawing.Color.

But this feels like serious overkill.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: AFAIK, in C# you can do this using Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnumType), "Red") maybe that can help with a direction?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

```
var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Plain and simple, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

[System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter.aspx) is how the XamlReader does it.

```
var result = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red") as Color;
```

Comment: I like this method. Very short and easy to use.

Answer (score 14):

**New and better answer**

Of course, ColorConverter is the way to go. Call [ColorConverter.ConvertFromString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606533.aspx) and cast the result. Admittedly this will involve boxing. If you want to avoid boxing, build a dictionary up to start with for the standard names (still using ColorConverter) and then use the dictionary for subsequent lookups.

**Original answer**

You could fairly easily fetch the property names and values from [System.Windows.Media.Colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx) once into a map:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Color> KnownColors = FetchColors();

public static Color FromName(string name)
{
    return KnownColors[name];
}

private static Dictionary<string, Color> FetchColors()
{
    // This could be simplified with LINQ.
    Dictionary<string, Color> ret = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Colors).GetProperties())
    {
        ret[property.Name] = (Color) property.GetValue(null);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It's a bit ugly, but it's a one-time hit.

Comment: For anyone looking for that simplified linq version: `typeof(Colors).GetProperties().ToDictionary(pi => pi.Name, co => (Color)co.GetValue(null));`  :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code makes translating name to `Color` class faster:

```
public class FastNameToColor
{
    Dictionary<string, Color> Data = new Dictionary<string, Color>();

    public FastNameToColor()
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] lColors = typeof(System.Drawing.Color).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in lColors)
        {
            object val = pi.GetValue(null, null);
            if (val is Color)
            {
                Data.Add(pi.Name, (Color)val);
            }
        }
    }

    public Color GetColor(string Name)
    {
        return Data[Name];
    }
}
```

You can expand this code to translate name to `Media.Color` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, another easier way is just use microsoft built static class, ex Colors.Red

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb189018.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> This code makes it easier to Convert Hex string to brush in c#, wpf

```
var brush = (Brush)new 
System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#28808080");
```