# Shape type binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I've bind `ObservableCollection` of Layer to a `TreeView` in WPF .

Layer definition is :

```
public class Layer 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public GeoType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum GeoType { Area, Line, Point }
```

This is `TreeView` XAML :

```xml
<TreeView  Grid.Column="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubLayers}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Canvas Background="LightGray">
                    <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}"
                             Height="15"
                             Width="15"
                             StrokeThickness="5"
                             Stroke="{Binding Color}"/>
                </Canvas>

                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I want to specify shape type based on `GeoType` property. I mean if `GeoType` is Line instead of canvas in above XAML it should be Line.
How can I do it using binding? Should I create converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the with pure XAML.

```xml
...
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LineTemplate">
        <Line />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EllipseTemplate">
        <Ellipse />
    </DataTemplate>
    ... etc
</Window.Resources>
...

<TreeView  Grid.Column="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubLayers}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Canvas Background="LightGray">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="{StaticResource local:GeoType.Line}">
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LineTemplate}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="{StaticResource local:GeoType.Ellipse}">
                                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EllipseTemplate}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Canvas>

                <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

It is only one of many possible solutuion. **local** is the namespace where your **GeoType** is. You should decorate the templates inside the resources to use data binding.

Comment: Thanks . It's very helpful. How can I bind color of shapes from Color property ?

Comment: Thanks . It's very helpful , as you said "You should decorate the templates inside the resources to use data binding" 
Is this right : 
        <Contract:GeoType x:Key="local:GeoType.Line" />
        <Contract:GeoType x:Key="local:GeoType.Area" />
        <Contract:GeoType x:Key="local:GeoType.Point" />
--------
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="{StaticResource local:GeoType.Line}">
                                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LineTemplate}" />
                                            </DataTrigger>

Comment: the same way you do it before - but inside the resource DataTemplates. Your DataContext will be of type Layer, and you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672991/how-do-i-convert-a-string-like-red-to-a-system-windows-media-color) to get the true Color, instead of string.